# Closing parent jsp when response is pushed

Tags: javascript, jsp

I'm opening a jsp(child jsp) from another jsp(parent jsp) using window.open() in the same parent frame. The child jsp pushes a zip to the client using ServletOutputStream in HttpServletResponse. When the response is pushed i.e after the save dialog box appearing I want the parent window also to close.
But it's not happening. Anybody with any suggested workaround?

Thanks in advance .